# checkbox update after row click not quite working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm basically a super beginner in javascript (and web development in general). Trying to add a feature to my HTML table that *checks the checkbox in the row that is clicked on.* This is the code I'm using:

```
    function selectRow(row)
{
    var firstInput = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
}
```

and in the HTML:

```
<tr onclick='selectRow(this)'>
```

It works when you click on the row. The problem is that when you click on the checkbox itself, it doesn't work. I'm guessing it's being double clicked? Not sure what to do about it though.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: post relevant html

Comment: Double click is what might be happening. You can add an event listener on the checkbox and invoke `event.preventDefault()` to disable default checking for checkbox.

Comment: Sort of worked... although I used check1.checked = !check1.checked; on the event listener instead because the event.preventDefault() was not working for some reason. Problem now is that this table is generated using a loop in php. Not sure how to call each checkmark in javascript now...

Comment: Should I post another question?

Comment: Note, when I say it worked, I only knew how to try it on the first checkmark in the table. (By using "id = chk$i" and then getElementByID('chk1').

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Nandu Kalidindi is the right way for you to solve the problem.

When you click on your checkbox, both events fire. The checkbox is checked by your table row, and it is checked by the checkbox. So it is double checked - which means that nothing will happen.

Because of event bubbling, even if you do event.preventDefault() on your checkbox, it will still be checked when you click on it (firing the tr event handler).